# Is there a way to set environment variables without a value while creating a Azure Container Instance?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I want to create a Azure Container Instance by using the website (https://portal.azure.com). The original docker command would look like this: `docker run -d my/image --min-port=49160 --fingerprint`.

On the advanced tab, I can enter a combination of key and value, for example `min-port` and `49152`. But I also need to set `fingerprint` as key, without a value. This is not allowed and gives me an error message "Value must not be empty". Is there a solution, maybe with CLI?

Comment: It the console does not allow, you can set in dockerfile. `ENV fingerprint=${DO_NOT_SET_VALUE}`. as ENV is key-value. so this is one trick to declare without value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CLI command to set the environment variable only with the variable and no value, the command would be like this:

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --environment-variables key1=value1 key2=''
```

Then the environment variable key2 only has the name, no value.